# Extract a block of text between two strings, repeat process throughout document

Tags: python, loops, text, extract

I am using python to attempt to read a txt file and pull out multiple blocks of text between strings. Here is an example:

```
something something something I dont want
Select and then any length and joins etc of text that I want which could be  multiple lines
: this semicolon is the end of what I want
something something something I dont want again
   Select and then any length and joins etc of text that I want which could be  multiple lines
: this semicolon is the end of what I want
```

Select is where I want to start extracting data and ; is where I want to stop

This will repeat itself throughout a 900 page document.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you thought about using a `regex`?

Comment: I am open to using regex for sure. I just found it getting overly complicated

Comment: I would clearly define your requirements / constraints in terms of the text that you want to extract. From your example, it looks like you only want text contained in parenthesis, but it is not clear whatsoever without sample text and an attempt on your behalf.

Comment: regex will likely provide the simplest solution. Otherwise, I imagine you will need need to get `index` of "Start(" and ") End", and iterate in a much more complicated fashion

Comment: How would nested parentheses work?

Comment: This would seem to mean: (a) that the literal 'Start (' must begin on a new line; (b) that the same thing applies to the literal 'End'; and (c) that you want everything between the intervening parentheses.

Comment: ... also that the 'start' and 'end' literals will not appear within the parenthesised text.

Comment: forget the parentheses - they dont matter it was just a way of grouping the text that I would like to capture

Comment: Are you familiar with the State Machine concept?

Comment: I am not...but interested!

Comment: In this case:
- start code in state '0'
- read input line by line
- when you encounter 'Start" enter state '1' and begin to accumulate input
- as long as you are in state '0' ignore input
- when you encounter 'End' stop accumulating input, process it as a result and enter state '0'.
- When you encounter the end-of-input commence processing final work.

Comment: thank you Bill Bell

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you wouldn't use a regex (as it simply solves the problem).

The regex you're looking for is: `Select ((?:.*\n)+?):`

Basically "Select", capture everything till newline+colon, "colon".

Just use it together with `re.finditer` or `re.findall` and you'll be set. [Test in regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1ciy6k/2).